# ROS ORB-Slam2 Map Point Vector is Empty

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, ros, camera-calibration, slam

I am trying to get mapping to work with ROS. I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with a Picamera v2 running ROS Noetic. It is running `cv_camera_node` to broadcast the camera images. I also have an Ubuntu 20.04.1 running ROS Noetic along with ORB-SLAM2. I was able to get the `debug_image` to display the grayscale image with the green lines. I can't get it to pass the initialization stage. The debug image keeps on saying "Trying to initialize" and the output of the ORB Slam launch file says, "Map point vector is empty!" I was able to get it to work twice but I don't know how. How do I properly calibrate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue before. I was able to get around this by applying [this patch](https://github.com/raulmur/ORB_SLAM2/issues/59#issuecomment-328763548) and trying different image sizes to see what worked best.

Comment: I tried that but just got errors. I think the other answer works better for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot of points, about 300, to get it to pass this stage. Try to find a thing with an intricate design like a fan that has the fancy blade guard or a messy desk. That will have close to 300 points needed for calibration.